# preventDefault() for keypress cancels change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling

In the code snippet below, I'm trying to prevent the user from entering new lines into a `<textarea>` by using `preventDefault()`. Instead of entering new lines, I want the enter key to trigger the blur event.  However, the code below is bypassing the change event after the user changes the text within the `<textarea>` and then hits enter.  How can I ensure that the change event always fires when the value of the text is changed?

```
$('textarea')
.keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {//13 = Enter
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).blur();
    }
})
.change(function() {// THIS DOES NOT FIRE IF USER PRESSES ENTER
    alert('change event');
})
.blur(function() {
    console.log('blur event');
});//end: blur()
```

Comment: _I'm trying to prevent the user from entering new lines into a textarea_ Mmmmm...seems like what you need is a text input.

Comment: That would be a good option, but there are cases where the user will need to enter a lot of text - more than will fit on one line.

Comment: Trigger the change event manually `$('textarea').change();` or `$(this).change();` when you are preventing the default behaviour.

Comment: You could possibly check against the textbox's defaultValue attribute... http://jsfiddle.net/RuhK4/

Comment: @Aamir: I only want the change event triggered when the value of the textarea is actually changed.

Comment: It is working fine in this sample http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g4ybc/ which browser r u using? Both Chrome and Firefox r working

Comment: @Arun: Thanks. I should have tested out this dummied down version of the code.  It seems there must be something else in my code (not shown in the example I shared) that is causing the problem.

Comment: @jake it is not working in IE though, but this is working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g4ybc/1/ in IE, here instead of firing `blur` event focus is changed to another object

Comment: What I don't understand is why? Why create confusion by blurring the element when pressing enter? It doesn't make much sense in terms of usability...

Comment: @elclanrs: why? b/c after the blur event, I'm trying to change the textarea a span tag filled with the value of the textarea. I think my issue was that I was replacing the textarea before the change event had a chance to fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is a problem with the event [ordering](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2007/02/06/event-order-of-blur-and-change/). In IE `change` event is fired first then `blur` event is fired but in Firefox and Chrome it is the opposite. So when you fire `blur()` event manually in Firefox and Chrome it causes the `focus` event to fire, but in IE it won't.

Comment: Since I couldn't rely on the ordering of the change & blur events across browsers, I ended up getting rid of the change event listener and instead built in that same functionality into the blur event: looking to see if the new textarea value was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the change event manually, the same way you trigger the blur event.